# How to express factors multiplication in visualization?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, visualization, data-visualization

I have a score formula (example):

```
score = (price^2) * (distance^0.5) * (popularity/0.5)
```

I want to visualize the impact of each factor on the score **for specific score** (for example score = 100 so the chart should express the contribute of each factor for the score). What is the proper way to do this ?

In case the formula was addition formula then bar chart which combined all factors with their relative impact was a good choice to show the impact of each factor on the score, but in case of multiplicity bar chart is not an option.

I am looking for a single chart which will express each factor impact.
I plan to do this in javascript.

Comment: For simplicty, keep all but one parameters constant and try and plot the graph i.e. `y = f(x)`. You can use `<canvas>` for the drawing.

Comment: What do you mean by *visualize* - charts?

Comment: @NateBarbettini - I edit the question to explain more.

Comment: @AvihaiMarchiano In case you want sophisticated data visualization, have you has a look at d3.js ?

Comment: @AkashPradhan - i want single graph that will show each factor impact . Something like combined bar chart.

Comment: @AkashPradhan - i am not client side developer , but after i will find the suitable chart/graph for this i will find the way to implement (d3/google/jquery)

Comment: @AvihaiMarchiano Have a look at the examples : https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery
I would have gone for the parameterized form - keeping all but 1 constant. If you are willing to go 3D with WebGL, then you can keep two variable, rest constants and switch between them with options.

Comment: I think his problem is more related to the approach rather than the technology.

Comment: @MarcoCI - agree. this is what i am looking for.

Comment: Do you have to show multiple scores or just one? Do you want to compare them?

Comment: @MarcoCI - YES! 
I am doing it for debug tool , so i want to show how this one is compare to the 3 winners.
I will be glad also to give analyze of single one result to show how each factor impact score, but my main target is to show it in compare to the 3 winners.